# Prometheus alertmanager.yml file gives unmarshal error

Tags: unmarshalling, prometheus-alertmanager

```
msg="Loading configuration file failed" 
file=alertmanager.yml 
err="yaml: unmarshal errors:\n  line 3: cannot unmarshal !!str 
`basic_auth` into config.plain\n  line 4: field username not found in 
type config.plain\n  line 5: field password not found in type 
config.plain\n  line 20: cannot unmarshal !!map into 
[]*config.WebhookConfig"
```

Below is the yml file, how to resolve this?

```yaml
global: 
  http_config: basic_auth
  username: 1234
  password: 1234
inhibit_rules: 
  - 
    equal: 
      - alertname
      - dev
      - instance
    source_match: 
      severity: critical
    target_match: 
      severity: warning
receivers: 
  - 
    name: web.hook
    webhook_configs: 
      http_config: global.http_config
      url: "http://localhost:8080"
route: 
  group_by: 
    - alertname
  group_interval: 5m
  group_wait: 30s
  receiver: web.hook
  repeat_interval: 1h
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```yaml
global: 
  http_config:
    basic_auth:
      username: 1234
      password: 1234
```